# Android Programming, ListView Images are gone during and after query in the SearchView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, searchview, listadapter

I'm having trouble trying to re-display the ListView's original values with it's respective Icons after I try to query Search in the SearchView. The ListView firsts display the items with the icons but disappears when trying to search and after. A help is so much appreciated, Thank you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.asus.sdssuanhandbookapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MySimpleAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_article);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.article_list);

        adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String temp : items) {
                    if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                        templist.add(temp);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, templist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);



                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



}
```

**MySimpleAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.asus.sdssuanhandbookapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by asus on 2/9/2017.
 */

public class MySimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;
    int[] imgs = {R.drawable.icn1,
            R.drawable.icn2,
            R.drawable.icn3,
            R.drawable.icn4,
            R.drawable.icn5,
            R.drawable.icn6,
            R.drawable.icn7,
            R.drawable.icn8,
            R.drawable.icn9,
            R.drawable.icn10,
            R.drawable.icn11,
            R.drawable.icn12,
            R.drawable.icn13,
            R.drawable.icn14,
            R.drawable.icn15,
            R.drawable.icn16,
            R.drawable.icn17,
            R.drawable.icn18,
            R.drawable.icn19,
            R.drawable.icn20,
            R.drawable.icn21,
            R.drawable.icn22
    };



    static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public MySimpleAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;


        if (rowView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            //Configure view holder
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.articleTxt);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.articleImage);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = names[position];
        int icon = imgs[position];
        holder.text.setText(s);
        holder.text.setTextSize(13);
        holder.image.setImageResource(icon);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/articleImage"
        android:src="@drawable/icn1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/articleTxt"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.asus.sdssuanhandbookapplication.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the actual shots of the app process:

[Here is the Original ListView display on App first Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhiOz.png)

[Then when trying to query on Search, and displays the same after which Icons were gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBsET.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this in main

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MySimpleAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_article);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.article_list);

        adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, items, null);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                int[] indexs = new int[items.lenght];
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {


                    if (items[i].toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                        // getting String data
                        tempList.add(items[i]);
                        // getting index for images
                        indexs[j] = i;
                        j++;

                    }
                }
                // MySimpleAdapter with 3 parameters
                adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, tempList.toArray(new String[tempList.size()]), indexs);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


}
```

and in MySimpleAdapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MySimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;
    private final int[] indexs;

    int[] imgs = {R.drawable.icn1,
            R.drawable.icn2,
            R.drawable.icn3,
            R.drawable.icn4,
            R.drawable.icn5,
            R.drawable.icn6,
            R.drawable.icn7,
            R.drawable.icn8,
            R.drawable.icn9,
            R.drawable.icn10,
            R.drawable.icn11,
            R.drawable.icn12,
            R.drawable.icn13,
            R.drawable.icn14,
            R.drawable.icn15,
            R.drawable.icn16,
            R.drawable.icn17,
            R.drawable.icn18,
            R.drawable.icn19,
            R.drawable.icn20,
            R.drawable.icn21,
            R.drawable.icn22
    };


    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public MySimpleAdapter(Activity context, String[] names, int[] indexs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.indexs = indexs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;


        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            //Configure view holder
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.articleTxt);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.articleImage);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = names[position];
        int icon;
        if(indexs == null) {
           icon = imgs[position];
        }
        else{
           icon = imgs[indexs[position]];
        }
        holder.text.setText(s);
        holder.text.setTextSize(13);
        holder.image.setImageResource(icon);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciated but Error is found Sir :( here it says after compiling the app:
**Error:(62, 27) error: unexpected type
required: reference
found:    int**
and
**Error:(66, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable temp**
The error detects in the `ArrayList<int>` where **int** underlines red
also, in the `tempList.add(temp);` where **temp** also has red
lastly, `adapter = new MySimpleAdapter( this, items, temIndexList);` where inside the bracket are all underlined red.. PLEASE HELP..

Comment: change the `temp` to `items[i]` and `int` to `Integer` and you have to change the code inside the MySimpleAdapter class then error will be solved

Comment: I followed what you commented Sir and got this **one error**:
`Error:(71, 47) error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnQueryTextListener> cannot be converted to Activity` Please help sir.. Thank you..

Comment: Sir the icons worked but whenever I do the **Search**, the **App crashes** saying: **Unfortunately, SDSSU-LC Handbook has stopped**. what went wrong Sir? :( Here is the _image link_ Sir: [app stopped](http://imgur.com/hJemxAo) Please help Sir :(

Comment: look at the Android Monitor its placed at the bottom left corner in Android studio there when the app crashes error will be displayed. make sure that your phone is connected while debugging

Comment: there is no error in the log error sir it just crashes when you do the search.. :( try it running sir.. Here is the log: [app log](http://imgur.com/nBi2pcZ)

Comment: will you please try it running sir? it seriously crashes whenever i do the search but without error in the log.. Please help..

Comment: the error has been solved and i have edited the above code

Comment: OH GOD! Thank you so very much Sir! You saved me!! :))

Comment: glad to help and one more thing try RecyclerView instead of ListView RecyclerView is the updated version of listView

Comment: Thanks again! May you give me a sample code using recycler view such apps like a dictionary app or handbook app? Like a manual app sir..

Answer (score 0):

first when the listView is created you are using MySimpleAdapter when the search occurs you are calling different ArrayAdapeter the id for images are inside that of MySimpleAdapter. you wont be able to use those images

Comment: Thanks for the note sir, but how can I code this one to display those images as well? Please please help..